# How to get the type of a nested xsd schema element in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

My problem is as follows:
I have a bunch of Xpath queries, and I want to be able to get the **type** of the elements that these queries resolve to, but form the underlying **xsd schemas**.
So for example given the schema:

```
...
 <xs:complexType name="ResultType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="BUS" type="m:VectorType" />
      <xs:element name="VM" type="m:VectorType" />
      <xs:element name="VA" type="m:VectorType" />
      <xs:element name="QG" type="m:VectorType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="VectorType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
...
```

and the query `//BUS/Value` I want to be able to check what the type of `//BUS/Value` is programmatically (from Java code). I've got as far as parsing the schema using ApacheXMLSCHEMA, XSOM, etc. but once I have the parsed schema, none of these libararies seem to offer me a way of directly getting the type of a nested element such as the one above.
Is there a way to do this, or do I have to break up the xpath query into BUS and Value, get the type of BUS and then look up the type of Value in that complex type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the answers above are valid solutions, however the approach I decided to go for was one suggested by a colleague.

for each xpath for a given schema:

1. generate a complete instance of that schema (easy to do using some tool such as trang). By complete I mean that all optional elements/attributes are present.
2. Parse the instance into a dom4j Document, and use the xpath on that instance to get a list of nodes.
3. For each of those nodes get its absolute path (from the root of the schema instance document).
4. parse the schema using some schema parsing library (I'm using XSOM)
5. Traverse the parsed schema recursively to get the type of each node from 3. (this will be easy , as you have each node's absolute path).

Voila! you have extracted the type of each node that this Xpath could bind to in a schema instance, but from the schema itself:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is anything in the Java libraries to do what you want directly.

Interpreting the XPath expressions would be a big work: you'll have to parse them and then interpret/execute them navigating the schema - quite complex unless you limit yourself to very simple XPaths.

A possible easier solution would be to write some code that builds an 'annotated' XML starting from the schema, something like:

```
<BUS myns:type="ResultType">
    <Value myns:type="VectorType">
      . . . 
    </Value>
 <BUS>
```

where `myns` is the prefix of a separate namespace. You then execute the XPath against this XML, and get the type from the `myns:type` attribute of the resulting node.

Generating this sample XML from the schema should be easier that handling directly the XPaths - especially if you already have classes to parse the schema.

Comment: Yeah this would be a quick fix, but the problem is that every time the schema changes I would have to manually update the instance file with the type info. Doesn't seem very scalable...

Comment: What I meant was to generate the instance XML file automatically from the schema - I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

XSOM supports something [schema component designators](http://xsom.java.net/nonav/javadoc/com/sun/xml/xsom/SCD.html) (SCD) that is roughly analogous to XPath for searching schema types. I found it to be a bit confusing and poorly documented, but it would seem to be exactly what you're looking for.